# Select objects with popularity "over 25" int the last week

Tags: mysql

My idea is something like

```
SELECT os.date, os.popularity
FROM object_stats os
WHERE os.date>='2021-04-01' AND os.popularity>'25 in one of those days'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e55866/1

Is this possible in one query?

Comment: Can you simplify the problem? A data set comprising a dozen rows, and a corresponding result is normally enough for most problems on here.

Comment: unclear what you want;  the popularity for all days in the last week but only if there is popularity > 25 on one of the days, and otherwise no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to know the `object_id` values for any objects which have popularity > 25 in one or more of the preceding seven days. This subquery gets you the object ids and dates with those popularities. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a86c95/9).

```sql
  SELECT object_id, date, SUM(popularity) popularity
    FROM object_stats
    WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY object_id, date
   HAVING SUM(popularity) > 25
```

And this main query, using the subquery, gets you a list of the object_id values meeting that criterion, along with their popularity score for each object's most popular day. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a86c95/8)

```sql
SELECT object_id, MAX(popularity) popularity
  FROM (
         SELECT object_id, date, SUM(popularity) popularity
           FROM object_stats
          WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
          GROUP BY object_id, date
         HAVING SUM(popularity) > 25
       ) days
 GROUP BY object_id
 ORDER BY MAX(popularity) DESC
```

If you don't care about the maximum popularity score, it's even simpler. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a86c95/10).

```sql
  SELECT DISTINCT object_id
    FROM object_stats
    WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY object_id, date
   HAVING SUM(popularity) > 25
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)